# Supabase fetch images in front end with react and next js from bucket storage

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storage, supabase, bucket

i have an account in supabase and i write this code for fetching images in front end with react, but it doesnt works (it appears null i dont know why). Does anyone knows if is a problem of policy in the bucket (i have it public) or any idea or doc site for this?

thanks

```
import { createClient } from '@/utils/supabase/server'

import { cookies } from 'next/headers';

export default async function Images() {

const cookieStore = cookies()

const supabase = createClient(cookieStore);

const {data,error} = await supabase.storage.from('10dias').list() 

console.log({data, error});

return null

}
```

The array gives me null in the terminal, no images where located